# how to create a new column in a dataframe using a loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I would like to make a new variable, called snapavg, using a loop.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the dataframe]

For each Name, I would like to make a loop that:

- if week =1, I would like to return the average as just TouchSnapPercentage
- if week =2, I would like to return the average as TouchSnapPercentage for week 1 + week 2 for each  divided by 2
- if week =3, divided by 3 so on and so forth.

Whatever I've tried so far isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'date': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'user': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
}
```

Get result:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.sum([df[(df.user == x.user) & (df.date == each)].iloc[0].value for each in range(1, x.date + 1)]) / x.date
     , axis=1)
```

If you have missing data (having data for one week but no data for previous):

```
df.apply(
    lambda x: np.sum(
        [df[(df.user == x.user) & (df.date == each)].iloc[0].value
         if df[(df.user == x.user) & (df.date == each)].shape[0] is not 0 else 0
         for each in range(1, x.date + 1)]) / x.date, axis=1)
```

You might want to rewrite this as function, the readability of this code is bad.

Comment: TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I believe the issue may stem from the for I in range. Thank you!

Comment: nvm, i guess range does not support such operation, should use apply instead

Comment: IndexError: ('single positional indexer is out-of-bounds', 'occurred at index 138'). The dataframe is 138 rows long, so this may be the problem.

Comment: it may be due to the .iloc[0]

Comment: Do you have all the data for each Name in each week?

Comment: Oh see why, I will have to adjust for that but it should work thereafter. Thank you.